# 403 forbidden for image url but not for css - M2

Tags: magento2, 404, http-status-403

Css and js file can be open from browser:

http://127.0.0.1/abc/pub/static/version1636623700/frontend/Pqr/xyz/en_US/mage/calendar.css

Image is available at location.

Loadin Properly from cms-pages.

Image URL: http://127.0.0.1/abc/pub/media/cms-pages/background_image.png

Not loading from **catalog/category**

Image URL: http://127.0.0.1/abc/pub/media/catalog/category/test.png

Image URL giving error:

> Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource.
>
> Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to
> use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
>
> Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) Server at 127.0.0.1 Port 80

URL Rewrite is enable. 777 pemission given to pub folder.

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this command :

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
sudo chmod -R 777 var/ generated/ pub/
```